# need help in computing a norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis

find the norm of the operator \varphi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}x(\frac{1}{k})}{k^{2}} in C[0,1] *emphas[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLSv.png)ized text*